# Simple good way to fit a 2D dataset consisting of positive and negative examples such that the function is monotonic in both dimensions

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a set of positive and negative samples in 2D $(x, y)$, and I would like to fit a curve $f$ to this data set so that $f(x, y_c)$ is increasing in $x$ and $f(x_c, y)$ is increasing in $y$. The function $f(x, y)$ can be thought of as the probability that a new random sample from point $(x, y)$ is positive. The function $f$ can be arbitrary (I wouldn't assume that it's linear or logarithmic or even a fixed-degree polynomial), but it should be smooth. For example, one idea is to bucket the samples into rectangles, compute the probability of a positive sample from each bucket, and then deal with any violations to monotonicity. (This is a little simple; it might be preferable to incorporate the data from neighboring buckets in some way.)

Is there a standard technique for solving this problem?

Comment: I have an idea how to approach this but please tell me first what x_c,y_c do represent.

Comment: I suppose that he means that the first derivative of f with respect to x and the first derivative of f with respect to y are positive.

Comment: i.e. he has prior information that values in the first quadrant are most likely to be positive.

Comment: @steffen, mzuba, yes, the partial derivatives with respect to both x and y are non-negative.